# Kolmogorov's continuity criterion Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, holder-spaces

Let $(X_t, t \in \mathbb{R})$ be an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process, i.e. $X_t$ is defined by
$$X_t = \sigma \int_{-\infty}^t e^{-\theta(t-s)} dW_s$$
for $t \in \mathbb{R}$ for parameters $\theta, \sigma > 0$.

Show that for an arbitrary compact interval $T \subset \mathbb{R}$ there exists constants $p,q,C > 0$ such that
$$\mathbb{E}|X_t - X_s|^p \leq C|t-s|^{1+q}$$
for all $s, t \in T$.

We want $q/p = 1/2$, so let $p=2$ and $q=1$, then
$$\mathbb{E}|X_t - X_s|^2 = \mathbb{E}X_t^2 - 2\mathbb{E}(X_t X_s) + \mathbb{E}X_s^2 \\
= \frac{\sigma^2}{2\theta} - 2\frac{\sigma^2}{2\theta}e^{-\theta|t-s|} + \frac{\sigma^2}{2\theta} \\
= \frac{\sigma^2}{\theta}(1 - e^{-\theta|t-s|}).$$

This should be smaller than $C|t-s|^2$ for all $s,t \in T$ for some $C > 0$. I cannot find this $C$, since $\frac{\sigma^2}{\theta}(1 - e^{-\theta|t-s|})$ will always be above $C|t-s|^2$ if $t-s \rightarrow 0$. The bigger $C$ is chosen the 'earlier' the inequality will hold, but it will never hold when $t \rightarrow s$ (if I'm correct).

What am I doing wrong? Actually I want to prove that the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process admits a version that is locally Hölder continuous of order strictly less than 1/2. I thought I should've made use of Kolmogorov's Continuity Criterion, but that doesn't seem to work out.

Does anyone know what I should do?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

I'm still having trouble when considering $p=4$ and $q=2$, because then I obtain
$$\mathbb{E}|X_t - X_s|^4 = \frac{3\sigma^4}{\theta^2}\left(e^{-\theta|t-s|} - 1\right)^2$$
and I can't find a $C>0$ such that 
$$\frac{3\sigma^4}{\theta^2}\left(e^{-\theta|t-s|} - 1\right)^2 \leq C|t-s|^3$$
for all $s,t \in \mathbb{R}$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps the choice $p=2$ is inadequate (as it is for Brownian motion). Try $p=4$.

Comment: That could be possible! But then I obtain $\mathbb{E}(X_t - X_s)^4 = \mathbb{E} X_t^4 - 4\mathbb{E} (X_t^3 X_s) + 6\mathbb{E} (X_t^2 X_s^2) - 4\mathbb{E}(X_t X_s^3) + \mathbb{E} (X_s^4)$ and I don't know the expressions for these expectations. In my book it is only given that $\mathbb{E} X_t X_s = \frac{\sigma^2}{2\theta}e^{-\theta|t-s|}$ and I don't know how that's are derived.

Comment: The odd moments will vanish. Since $X_s$ is Gaussian, the fourth moment is three times the square of the variance. If $X$ and $Y$ are (joint) standard normal with covariance $\rho$, then $\Bbb E[X^2Y^2]=1+2\rho^2$. From this and scaling you can work out $\Bbb E[X_t^2X_s^2]$.

Comment: I am not following: are you trying to show that such $(C,p,q)$ exist? And afterwards, what allows you to decide that $(p,q)=(2,1)$ would do?

Comment: I have to show that the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process admits a version that is locally Hölder continuous of order strictly less than 1/2. Therefore I want to use Kolmogorov's continuity criterion which states: If $X$ is a real-valued process on compact interval $T \subset \mathbb{R}$ and there exist $p,q,C > 0$ such that $\mathbb{E}|X_t - X_s|^p \leq C|t-s|^{1+q}$ for all $s,t\in T$, then $X$ admits a continuous modification with sample paths that are almost surely Hölder continuous of order $\alpha$ for $\alpha < q/p$. That's why I want $p = 2q$.

Comment: I've edited my first post. I am still not able to find a $C > 0$ for $p = 4$ and $q=2$. Anyone? :)

Comment: I think what you were looking for, can be found here:
[https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3553131/an-easier-way-to-check-the-existence-of-continuous-modification-without-using-ch](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3553131/an-easier-way-to-check-the-existence-of-continuous-modification-without-using-ch)